# One of the view reloads the whole application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Clicking on one of the letters reloads the entire application (see gif). This behavior causes other problems, such as `rxjs` angular `BehaviorSubject` reboots the initial value, which also violates the entire logic of the application.

[image]

The routing of this component defined like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DictionaryPage
    },
    {
        path: 'letter/:letter',
        component: LetterPage
    },
    {
        path: 'add',
        component: WordAddComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'word-detail/:id',
        component: WordDetailComponent
    }
];
```

And this component is one of the dictionary module component:

[image]

Only this component's behavior restarts the entire application, while other components are loaded without restarting the application. For example, the 4th tab in the screenshot below depends on one of the `BehaviorSubject` and disappears because the application restarts and returns the original value of `BehaviorSubject`.

[image]

The dictionary module will be loaded through ionic tabs routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'admin',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../admin/admin.module#AdminPageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'home',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'dictionary',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren:
                            '../dictionary/dictionary.module#DictionaryPageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

I've created stackblitz project with the same behavior. It has a lot of errors but the main problem could be reproduced. If you click on the letter app will reload, could you guys please check it
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-uev2gt

Comment: The only way I've ever managed to get routing to work in Angular without either the app reloading, or getting a 404 from the server, was to put all of the routing after a `#`. I don't think that's supposed to be necessary, but I haven't figured out how to make it work otherwise.

Comment: The is new version of `ionic 4.7` on stackblitz, I'll provide working example soon, so you can touch the code https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16354#issuecomment-515100104

Comment: Added `letter.page.html`

Comment: @khashashin, I think it's because of `showSelectedLetterPopup` function.. can you let us see what's inside this function?

Comment: try to enable router tracing and maybe you will find something in console

Comment: @Reigel I updated the component code, could you take a look at that?

Comment: @khashashin, can you add `return false;` at the end of function `showSelectedLetterPopup(ltr: string)`, let's see if that changes things

Comment: I've added stackblitz project could you pleace check whats triggers this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Stackblitz doesn't work at all, so if you provide a demo, make sure it is a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**. Anyway, just looking at `dictionary-page.html` I found the issue. It's this line:

```html
<ion-card href="/tabs/dictionary/letter/{{letter}}">
```

You are using `href`, which reloads the page. You should take a habit of using angular's **[`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)** when you want to insert an link, to avoid this specific problem. So change your code to:

```html
<ion-card routerLink="/tabs/dictionary/letter/{{letter}}">
```